# MiniMagick Gem: How do I create a new blank image without a file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minimagick

I want to combine two images (one background image, one text image) into one big image.

I believe I have the background image done since it's just based off a file. However, I'm having trouble trying to create an image from scratch. Any tips?

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open("public/text_response_bg.png")
image.combine_options do |i|
  i.size "1024x512"
end

text = MiniMagick::Image.new #<-- does not work
text.combine_options do |i|
  i.size "700x200"
  i.gravity 'center'
  i.fill 'white'
  i.caption 'blahblahblah'
end

result = image.composite(text) do |c|
  c.compose "Over"
  c.geometry "+20+20"
end
```

Answer (score 9):

Create an image from scratch with the following Ruby Code:

```
MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |i|
 i.size "700x200"
 i.gravity "center"
 i.xc "white"
 i.caption "blablabla"
 i << "test_image.jpg"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

MiniMagick provide a method `MiniMagick::Image.create` to create a new image but seems not work with [this issues](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/59)

Use ImageMagick primary command you can create a pure color image like

```
convert -size 800x600 xc:"#ffffff" write.jpg
```

So if not mind using system command to create image you can do:

```
cmd = "convert -size 800x600 xc:'#ffffff' WRITE_IMAGE.jpg"
system(cmd)
```

UPDATE: I use MiniMagick 3.8.0, and see latest version 4.0.1 has a `MiniMagick::Shell` class, think it could run that custom ImageMagick command directly.

Comment: yeh i was thinking that too.. but it doesn't seem too clean. I'll consider it as an option though. thanks!